# Firebase Admin in app engine - The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get Firebase admin to work on my local debugging appengine instance, but I'm failing miserably. I have version 4.1.2.
This is the setup:

```
InputStream serviceAccount = GroupsServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/service.json");
                FirebaseCredential cred = FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount);
                FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setCredential(cred)
                        .setDatabaseUrl("https://<...>.firebaseio.com")
                        .build();

FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
this.database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

And I try to call setValue like this:

```
Task<Void> t = this.database.getReference("groups").child(key).setValue(data);
Tasks.await(t);
```

While in debugger I can see the console window getting flooded with exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: response was a python exception:
cgoogle.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors
ApplicationError
p0
(I1
tp1
Rp2
(dp3
S'application_error'
p4
I1
sS'error_detail'
p5
S'system_error:10049 error_detail:"The requested address is not valid in its context"'
p6
sb.
```

Any ideas? I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. The `service.json` file is taken directly from firebase console.

Comment: I just experienced this error too. I was hoping someone had an answer by now.